# On which island can I find an abundance of Strawberry Bushes?

Tags: seabeard

I've been tasked with finding three strawberries from bushes scattered around the islands. Unfortunately, I've pulled up every bush on three islands now and only found one strawberry. IN the interest of minimizing the time I spend waiting around for them to grow back, which island has the most fruit-bearing bushes for me to pluck?